# How am I able to combine the columns from the two tables in one datagrid and use join in Silverlight?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria

I have created a RIA services solution with help from [MSDNs walkthrough.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707376%28v=vs.91%29.aspx/) I have two datagrids that shows data from two tables. One datagrid shows material and the other one the component parts (Sortiment in swedish). But I would like to combine these two tables since the component parts-ID in component parts table is also represented in the material table.

How am I able to combine the columns from the two tables in one datagrid and use join in Silverlight?

```
  public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private DomainService1 _materialContext = new DomainService1();
        private DomainService1 _sortimentContext = new DomainService1();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        #region Material 
        EntityQuery<Material> query =
       from c in _materialContext.GetMaterialQuery()
       where c.tillverkningsorderID.Equals(1)
       orderby c.materialID
       select c;

        //LoadOperation<Material> loadOp = this._materialContext.Load(this._materialContext.GetMaterialQuery());
        LoadOperation<Material> loadOp = this._materialContext.Load(query);
        myMaterialGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
        #endregion


        #region Sortiment
        LoadOperation<Sortiment> loadOp_S = this._sortimentContext.Load(this._sortimentContext.GetSortimentQuery());
        sortiment.ItemsSource = loadOp_S.Entities;
        #endregion





    }
```

**EDIT: It's a one to many-relationship**

Answer (score 0):

Is there a one-to-one relationship between `Material` and `Sortiment`? So you'd want a Sortiment object to have all the extra columns from a single row in your materials table?

If so, probably the easiest way is to create a data object that is the combination of these two tables. If you are using EntityFramework this is called [Entity Splitting](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-entity-splitting/), and means that your model can have a new single entity called whatever-you-like, that represents the joining of two sql tables.

Comment: Yes, it is a one-to-one relationship. Is it easy to be able to edit and save the changes in the database? I might use a dropdownlist in the datagrid as well.

Comment: If you are using EF to do the edit/save then yes ... it is as easy as it was before. If you're mapping the functions to stored procedures then obviously you'll need to manually sort that out. The gist of it is that rather than having two types of entities (`Material` and `Sortiment`) your model will have one type of entity (`MaterialWithSortiment`) and so all your data operations are on this new type. This is *splitting* an *entity* across multiple tables. EF will take care of usual crud stuff so long as you get the mapping right in the model.